# In the Doctor Who episode "Utopia", how do people in the distant future know English?

Tags: doctor-who

In the *Doctor Who* episode "Utopia", the main characters travel trillions of years into the future and find humans and "kind" (human-like people) speaking English. How do they know English? Languages evolve: the English of even a thousand years ago is unintelligible today, and trillions of years is almost unimaginably longer.

---

Notes:

- I've only ever watched two *Doctor Who* episodes ("Smith and Jones" and "Utopia", both from the new series), so this question may very well be answered clearly in another episode. (E.g., maybe there's some kind of force field around the Doctor and other major characters that serves the same purpose a Babelfish does in the Hitchhiker series.) If so, then please post that as an answer!
- The same question *could* be asked about other people in the two episodes I've seen (listed just above), such as the plasmivore, the slabs, and indeed the Doctor himself. But in all those cases, it's possible that they (even off-camera) learned English from anglophone humans (as indeed the rhinoceros-like police chief did). The same can't readily be said about the future humans and kind.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The Tardis has a built in [translation circuit](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Telepathic_circuits) in it.  Wherever the Doctor and his companions go, the Tardis automatically translates for them, even when they're out of it.  In *The Christmas Invasion*, while the Tenth Doctor is recovering from his regeneration, they have a problem with this and Rose has trouble understanding the aliens until the Doctor starts to recover.  (Actually, it's her understanding of the aliens that tips her off the Doctor is getting better.)

Comment: +1, and thank you! Could you elaborate a bit in the answer on how it works, Please? E.g., does it change sound waves of speech en route to listeners' ears? change something in listeners' brains?

Comment: I've added a link to the Dr. Who Wiki site page on the Telepathic Circuit; I think it will answer your questions.  Also see [Translation Circuit](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Translation_circuit) which is due to be merged in with the Telepathic Circuit shortly.

Comment: @KeithHWeston, thanks!

Comment: Elaborating about how anything in _Doctor Who_ works is counter-productive.  Unlike, say, _Star Trek_, this is not a universe where the "how" is important unless it effects a plot point - and then, things can change next time it effects a different situation.

Comment: @TangoOversway, and yet there is (it seems) a correct answer as to how the Doctor and the future people could understand one another. So some "how"s are productive, I guess. (I tend to be analytical, so for me "how" is always a question. If the show is of the sort that that's unproductive then I will probably stop watching it as soon as I discover that fact for myself.)

Comment: Further limitations of the translation circuit:  At the end of `A Good Man Goes to War`, River mentions that the Gallifreyan symbols on the cot don't translate (and, indeed, this is supported by the opening of `The Time of Angels`, earlier, where she leaves a message in Old High Gallifreyan, which Amy can't read), and that the circuit takes time to deal with a new language, so that the prayer leaf Amy was given at the start isn't shown translated until the end.

Comment: Also truly old text, such as from the Impossible Planet, can not be translated.